# Looking for word or phrase for when you look for something over and over in the same places unsuccessfully then find it there when you look again?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a word for phrase for when you look for something over and over in the same places unsuccessfully then find it there when you look again?

Comment: I have it written down here somewhere ... Let me look ...

Comment: The word changes based on how old you are.

Comment: "It's been staring me in the face all this time."

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence explaining how you wish to use it, please?

Comment: It's called a "man look" or "boy look" when a man or boy is looking for ages and when a woman or girl find it immediately.

Comment: Still can't find it!!

Answer (score 4):

[**be (right) under your nose**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-right-under-your-nose)

"I ​spent all ​morning ​looking for the ​book, and it was ​right under my nose the ​whole ​time."

Answer (score 1):

If it was a snake, it would have bit me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my world this is referred to as: man vision.

The canonical example being a search for milk in the refrigerator. The milk is front and center on the top shelf but the person has an inability to perceive it, and consequently searches all other areas of the refrigerator.

Comment: This is something I've never heard before, though I found it documented on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MtF/comments/rp9fnv/comment/hq3bz7s/). It brings an unnecessary gender stereotype, one that I assume is on its way out.