# English equivalent proverb for an absent minded person

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

There is a proverb in Hindi language **बगल में छोरा, गाँव में ढिंढोरा**
It means that a person has lost something and is searching every corner of the city. But, the lost thing is right with him which he realizes much later. It could also indicate a forgetful or an absent-minded person.

What is the English equivalent proverb or idiom for this?

Comment: I'm racking my brains, but finding nothing there. Maybe the answer is close at hand. There ought to be an idiom for this. Especially for the sensation experienced when one keeps looking in the same places for a lost object.

Comment: *Can’t see the wood for the trees* or more likely *can’t see the nose in front of your face* or perhaps *can’t see what’s in front of your nose*?
By the way 75512, we search either every corner or every nook and cranny… unless you did that on purpose…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Thank you for the correction. Somehow, the idiom is tweaked and used as 'every nook and corner' in the Indian subcontinent. It is probably Indianized English. Now, I know the right one.  Corrected my question too. https://targetstudy.com/knowledge/idiom/nook-and-corner.html http://shabdkosh.raftaar.in/Meaning-of-TO%20SEARCH%20EVERY%20NOOK%20AND%20CORNER-in-Hindi

Comment: @NigelJ have a memory like a sieve. Does it come anywhere close to this?

Comment: Really? I just assumed you'd slipped up. Sorry for that. *A memory like a sieve* suggests things are easily lost, but nothing about searching nooks or seeing noses.

Comment: The object was [right under his nose](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-right-under-your-nose) the whole time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for word or phrase for when you look for something over and over in the same places unsuccessfully then find it there when you look again?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302572/looking-for-word-or-phrase)

Comment: They'd [loose their head if it wasn't screwed on](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/would_lose_one%27s_head_if_it_wasn%27t_attached#:~:text=(humorous)%20Said%20of%20a%20person%20who%20habitually%20mislays%20things.).

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, [Mari-Lou-A](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/44619/mari-lou-a) wrote:

> The object was [right under his nose](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-right-under-your-nose) the whole time.

---

> **Right under your nose:** to be in a place that you can clearly see:
>
> - I spent all morning looking for the book, and it was right under my nose the whole time.
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-right-under-your-nose)]